# seeing application crash when trying to use strcpy

Tags: c++, c, dll

We have cpp dll, where I could narrow down to a line from where crash was arising. The line is related to copy, which is:

```
void GetCellText(HWND ssHwnd,char *& output){
  CString sData;
  ....
  ....
  strcpy (output, sData) //app crashes here
}
```

so I replaced the strcpy like this:

```
void copyToOutput(char *& output, CString sData) {
  int strLen = sData.GetLength();
  output = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * strLen + 1); // Allocate memory
  LPTSTR p = sData.GetBuffer(strLen);
  strcpy(output, p);
  output[strLen] = '\0'; // Null terminate
  sData.ReleaseBuffer();
}
```

however I am still seeing crash failure. Could you anyone suggest whatz incorrect with my fix.

Comment: Is `output` pointing to allocated memory, big enough to fit all in `sData`? And `sData` is not a wide-character string?

Comment: Oh, and is there a reason you use a C-style pointer to string instead of e.g. `CString` (or `std::string`) for the argument? As the function is called from C++ code anyway, you might as well use proper string classes.

Comment: The stack trace of your crash will be more informative than anything we can guess about your code here. Unrelated: pass `sData` by reference to your function; no sense in making any more copies of that thing than you have to. My *guess*: you're corrupting your heap somewhere else.

Comment: correct, from the calling function, there is a line called free(output), which is causing the crash. But my new issue is, called function has certain flows where my method is not called at all, i.e no malloc, i think this is causing free to crash. But how to check whether malloc or memory was allocated or not ??

Answer (score 0):

There may be a few issues with that code:

1. Never use `strcpy` because it is prone to overflow the destination buffer. In your case you know the length of the string being copied, there is no reason not to use `memcpy`, e.g. `memcpy(output, p, strLen)`.
2. This is C++ code, but the buffer is allocated using `malloc`. The caller of this code may accidentally use `free[]` to deallocate it. You may like to use `std::vector<char>` instead of the raw pointer.
3. You can directly access the underlying C-string without having to copy it using `CString::PCXSTR`.

Answer (score -2):

Use this and solve crash.

```
output=(char *) malloc(sData.GetLength());
strcpy(output,sData.GetString() );
```

Comment: from the calling function, there is a line called free(output), which is causing the crash. But my new issue is, called function has certain flows where my method is not called at all, i.e no malloc, i think this is causing free to crash. But how to check whether malloc or memory was allocated or not ?

Comment: This will crash because it doesn't allocate enough memory for output.